# AngularJS factory $http not returning object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, return, factory

I have the following factory and I don't want to return a promise, I want to return the object with that parameters and assing it to scope variable in my controller, but that's returning nothing. How can i solve this? Thank you.

```
app.factory('discoverViewModelFactory', function ($http) {
        return {
            createViewModel: function (crevitIdentityId) {
                return $http.get('/categories').then(function(categories) {
                    return $http.get('/advertisementAmount?crevitIdentityId=' + crevitIdentityId).then(function (advertisementAmount) {
                        return new marketplace.discoverViewModel(categories, advertisementAmount);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's an async operation, you don't really have any other (cleaner) option.

Comment: I could make an instance in the controller, but how can I return both categories and advertisementAmount here chaining the promises?

Comment: what code do you have in your controller?

Comment: `var app = angular.module('private');
(function (namespace) {
    var marketplace = namespace.require('private.marketplace');

    app.controller('discoverController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'discoverViewModelFactory', function ($scope, $rootScope, discoverViewModelFactory) {
        discoverViewModelFactory.createViewModel($rootScope.crevitIdentity.id).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }]);
})(namespace);`